# How do I save image and text data into the same iphone file so the user can print it out?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

This is a simplistic photo journal.  Pick a photo, add a caption, store them together, and let  the user print it.  Perhaps this isn't even the right approach, but there are a few things I could use some guidance on: (1) how to you store image and text data together so it is printable, (2) if you were putting multiple photo/captions in how can I enter a return between entries to separate them, and (3) is there a way to do the image and caption capture together to avoid repeating all the file identification, etc.  Right now I get the image saved, but not the caption.  I get that these are mixed types, but don't know a solution.  New to coding.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // User picks a photo from the their phone camera roll
    // Since iPhone simulator doesn't have photos, load and display a placeholder image
    NSString *fPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_1588" ofType:@"jpg"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fPath];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

    //Save image to file
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fPath];
    NSArray *DocumentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [DocumentsDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpeg"];
    NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
    [data2 writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

    //Display keyboard and image caption from user
    NSString *caption = enterCaption.text;

    // Write the caption at the end of the image file
    NSArray *DocumentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [DocumentsDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpeg"];
    NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
    [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [myHandle writeData:  [caption dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myHandle closeFile];
}

    //Dismiss Keyboard
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

I also couldn't get this `if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath], NO)` version of the code below to work.  Very puzzled by that.  Any clues?

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath], YES) {
        //Writing image to the created file
        NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
        // move to the end of the file to add data
        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        NSLog(@"caption written on existing file =%@", caption);
        [myHandle writeData:  [caption dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [myHandle closeFile];}
     else {
```